# dateFromString returns nil

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

This is my *NSString*,

```
myDate : 2011-06-07 11:23:47  0000
```

And this is the code,

```
NSTimeZone *currentDateTimeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
NSDateFormatter *currentDateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[currentDateFormat setTimeZone:currentDateTimeZone];
[currentDateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *tempDate = [currentDateFormat dateFromString:second];
```

Still *tempDate* gets the value `nil`.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you get the date string? It needs to be `2011-06-07 11:23:47 +0000` for this to work.

Comment: +1, but why it must be +0000. 0000 is not reason application must return nil, I think !

Comment: Because it indicates an offset value from the GMT. The offset is either +ve or -ve. `0000` isn't an offset representation.

Comment: But it cant be the reason that tempDate gets the value nil

Comment: What does `dateFromString:` return when it gets a string that doesn't conform to the date format set?

Comment: @ViTo - Not only can it be the reason, it is the reason. The Z format requires a "+" or "-" in front of the 0000. Without it, the string does not match the format so `dateFromString:` returns nil

Comment: i just set my current parser to : yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0000

Comment: Your date format is right. Set it back to what it was. The string is erroneous. How are you getting the string?

Comment: Oky, i got it. actually there was a problem in the webservice and i was getting a wrong string. Anyways, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,
**This is the function to get Date from String .**

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *convertedDate = [df dateFromString:stringDate];
[df release];
// [convertedDate description]
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setAMSymbol:@"AM"];
[formatter setPMSymbol:@"PM"];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:a"];
return [formatter stringFromDate:convertedDate];
```

Answer (score 1):

What I think is, it not related to TimeZone but the device 24hours settings.
Developer has to check if the device timings are of 24hours then they should use HH, and if the device timings are of 12hours then they should use hh.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSTimeZone *currentDateTimeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
NSDateFormatter *currentDateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] *autorelease*];
[currentDateFormat setTimeZone:currentDateTimeZone];
[currentDateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss *ZZZZ*"];
NSDate *tempDate = [currentDateFormat dateFromString:second];
```

Add ***autorelease*** and ***ZZZZ*** insead of Z.

Comment: Add autorelease I have same problem, and the reason of problem was that I do not have autorelease.

Comment: While the lack of `autorelease` may cause him to leak memory (unless there's a `release` somewhere else not shown), it won't have anything to do with the reason the date string can't be parsed. Changing the "Z" to "ZZZZ" does *not* make any difference in this code (try it!)